# Showing image from MongoDB that is stored as Buffer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am storing an image like this:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('pic'), (req, res) => {
var newImg = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
var encImg = newImg.toString('base64');
var s = new Buffer(encImg, 'base64');

var newCar = {
    picture: s,
    contentType: req.file.mimetype,
    link: req.body.link
}
})
});
```

Now the data looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 5a502869eb1eb10cc4449335,
    picture: Binary { _bsontype: 'Binary', 
                      sub_type: 0, 
                      position: 1230326, 
                      buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 
                      48 44 52 00 00 05 00 00 00 03 1e 08 06 00  ... >
                    },
    contentType: 'image/png', 
    link: 'fds', 
    __v: 0
}
```

I want to show this picture on frontend, like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

In my case, this code will be:

```
<img src="data:<%= c.contentType %>;base64, <%= c.picture %>" />
```

And all I am getting is some weird symbols:
[image: Image of FrontEnd Console]

I think I tried almost everything, and still can't figure out what is this. Even when I convert that Buffer toString('ascii'), I am still getting some symbols (boxes) that can't be recognized.

What am I supposed to do?
P.S. Also, is this a good way to store images? (less than 16MB), I think I noticed it's kinda slow, cuz of those long strings converting and reading file, compared to case where I just store the image as file?

Comment: Have you tried `c.picture.toString("base64")`?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I am puzzled with this too, storing as string could save some convention time. But some said buffer could save some space. I just need to store one image per document. may I know how did you solved yours? :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
   <img [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,'+Logo.data" height="50" width="60" alt="Red dot" />
```

Data from database:

```
 "Logo" : {
        "data" : BinData(0,"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/"),
        "name" : "dp.jpg",
        "encoding" : "7bit",
        "mimetype" : "image/jpeg",
        "truncated" : false,
        "size" : 895082
    }
```

Hope it help's